# Why would printing to a Printer cause an exception, when printing to .xps works just fine?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

I have content loaded into a FlowDocument, which has been loaded into a FlowDocumentReader control, acting as a Print Preview style window. I invoke the FlowDocumentReader.Print() method. This opens the print dialog box, listing all printers connected to my PC.

When printing to .xps (i.e., to file) everything prints as normal. When I attempt to print to a different device (a networked printer), I get the following exception:

```
System.Printing.Printjob Exception
"An exception occurred while calling XpsDocumentEvent."
```

The printer in question is properly connected. I can send other documents to it just fine. I have even set the networked printer to be the primary printer, but it had no effect.

I'm largely at a loss here. What should I be checking to diagnose and fix this issue?

Edit: Additionally, if I resume debugging after the exception is hit, Windows will say that the document was sent to printer successfully, yet no document was printed.

Edit 2: I was able to successfully print to a different network printer without changing any code. Removing then re-adding the original troublesome printer fixed the errors I was experiencing. The moral of the story? When in doubt, it's probably the printer's fault.

Comment: Can you test with a different (local) printer?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'd like to, but none are available

Comment: Have a look at the exception object in the watch window (or by logging out its properties). In particular pay attention to the `InnerException` property which may have the underlying cause. It may be you will have to drill down through each exception's inner exception until you find the root cause.

Comment: @PaulRuane that's a great idea. I use that frequently when debugging and it has been very helpful in many other situations. Unfortunately the InnerException property was set to null in this case.

Comment: @ford if you open the XPS in say IE and print from there (to the network printer) do you get the same error? If File > Print is disabled use Ctrl + P

Comment: The part that confuses me is the mention of XPS in the exception when you said you are printing to a real printer.

Comment: @JeremyThompson that's a good plan, I've tried that and .xps files would not print to the network printer (even .xps generated by MS Word), giving the same error as any other .xps file.

Comment: @PaulRuane I'm using XPS document classes to form the document to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully print to a different network printer without changing any code. Removing then re-adding the original troublesome printer fixed the errors I was experiencing. The moral of the story? When in doubt, it's probably the printer's fault. Perhaps this is more of a SuperUser question at this point.